# Кнопка в виде текста Swing

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте, есть ли в Swing возможность создавать кнопку в виде текста? то есть что-бы не было никаких рамок а просто текст на который нажимаешь и происходит действие?

Comment: создать JLabel добавить ей MouseListener

Comment: @keekkenen вот после такого и плодится ужасный UI, когда без мышки шагу ни ступишь...

Comment: @TagirValeev какой вопрос, такой ответ.. разумеется хоткеями IDEA тут и не пахнет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопку можно стилизовать, убрав часть отрисовки. Например, так:

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Полный пример:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame)null, "Разные кнопки") {
      {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new JButton("Обычная кнопка"));
        JButton button = new JButton("Кнопка без рамок");
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(l -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ура!"));
      }
    };
    dialog.setSize(200, 100);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: Внешний вид приложения]

При этом сохраняется поведение кнопки (фокус, таб-стоп, можно нажать как с клавиатуры, так и с мышки).